# Twitter account suspended—why?

Tags: twitter

I'm new using Twitter. I tried to follow someone (who is legit) and next thing I know
I get a message that my account has been suspended. It says I have been using it for spam or that someone might have hacked into it.

How can that be? I don't even know how to use Twitter, connect it to my Facebook etc. Even though I've had an account, I never really used it. The only thing I did was to change my password as I couldn't remember it. I'd like to talk to a support person but it seems that it's not even possible.

If I could email tech support, will I even hear back from them?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because it is asking for tech support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is only answerable by the company's admins.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing that we can do to help you. You're going to need to get in touch with Twitter support.

From the [Twitter Help Center](https://support.twitter.com/articles/15790-my-account-is-suspended):

> **How to tell if your account is suspended:**
>   If you suspect your account
>   is suspended, log in to Twitter.com. You should see a prompt informing
>   you that your account is currently suspended.
>
> **How to expedite the appeal process:**
>   To expedite the appeal process,
>   please check to make sure your account is currently suspended by
>   logging in.
>
> If your account is suspended, you’ll need to confirm that you have
>   changed the account behaviors that are in violation of the [Twitter
>   Rules](https://support.twitter.com/articles/18311-the-twitter-rules), or that you have removed all prohibited automation from your
>   account. For more information on best practices for using Twitter,
>   read this [article](https://support.twitter.com/articles/69214).
>
> **To appeal your account suspension:**
>   File a help request [here](https://support.twitter.com/forms/general?subtopic=suspended).

Comment: I tried to get in touch with them but can't find a phone number or email for tech support.  Sorry I thought this was a general place to ask questions about social media accounts.  I guess my post doesn't belong here.